Could someone explain this inconsistent System.IO.Directory.Exists() behavior?

I've been trying to understand how Windows performs path validation/normalization and have been doing some basic testing via .NET's System.IO.Directory, System.IO.File, and System.IO.Path classes. For reference, I'm using PowerShell 7.4.2 on Windows 10 (which I believe uses .NET 8.0.4).
According to this Microsoft blog:

Normally any path passed to a Windows API is (effectively) passed to GetFullPathName() and normalized. There is one important exception- if you have a device path that begins with a question mark instead of a period.  It must use the canonical backslash- if the path does not start with exactly \\?\ it will be normalized.

and:

It is important to recognize, however, that forward slashes are not supported in Windows outside of this normalization step.

Despite this, when working with non-normalized UNC paths, it appears that forward slashes are accepted as valid path separators in some places but not others (as shown in the screenshot).
From my testing, .NET's System.IO classes seem to correctly avoid normalizing paths that start with \\?\, as calling System.IO.Path.GetFullPath() on such paths doesn't convert forward slashes or collapse repeated separators.
Additionally, System.IO.Directory.Exists(), System.IO.File.Exists(), and System.IO.Path.Exists() seem to consistently reject non-normalized paths containing / for non-UNC paths, but for UNC paths is seems to depend on the location of the separator. From what I can tell, forward slashes are treated as invalid up to and including the separator dividing the share name from its top-level directory, but may be valid further along the path. I say "may" because this doesn't seem to hold true for UNC paths where the host name is LOCALHOST:


Bottom line: just use backslashes.
